# J2Me 3.0 SDK and Java Wireless toolkit 2.5.2 don't work

Tags: installation, java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

I have Windows 7 64 bit + Intel 64 bit

I developed MIDlets , but J2Me 3.0 SDK and Java Wireless toolkit 2.5.2 don't work.

I reinstall Netbeans(Largest one ) , J2Me 3.0 SDK and Java Wireless toolkit.

What should I do to have Java Platform to execute any Midlet?

The applications J2SE works fine.

Answer (score 1):

It is down to your installation of the Java that will be 64bit. Simple download 32bit version that will reside in **C:\Program Filesx86\Java** and then reinstall your WTKs and link them to your 32bit Java. That what I did for Sony Ericsson WTK and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the properties of your application.

In Netbean Right click on Your Project-> Properties->Application Descriptor->tab Midlets & then click on button Add.